# Angular: how to initialize variable inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-template

I have an Angular template:

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of list | keyvalue" let-rand="random()">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio-{{rand}}" name="field-radio" 
    [value]="item.key">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-{{rand}}">
    {{ item.key }}
  </label>
</li>
```

I want to execute `random()` function for every iteration of loop. But I get an error:

> Property 'random' does not exist on type...

How can I use internal variable inside Angular template?

Comment: if you want to get a unique number, you can use index. it is auto increment

Comment: You will have to create a method called `rand` in your typescript code that makes a call to `Math.random` (and I assume multiply with something and use floor)

Comment: @ShamPooSham method is already there, the reason of issue is something else.

Comment: If you have an array called list, you can simply use the map method in the ngOnInit and call your rand() function from there

Comment: The `let-` syntax won't do anything, it only works with directives that have support for the specific variable. ngFor does not have support for the rand template variable, so it means nothing. What I would do is to create a new list that includes the key and the random number.

Comment: @ShamPooSham so in other words, no way to use template variable into loop?

Comment: @Osakr can I do it into angular template?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy You can use the values in the tempalte, but you cannot put that logic in the template. Take a look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-whkem9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: The best you can do is through ngTemplateOutlet like one answer says (although it got some syntax wrong). But creating a new pipe (like the keyvalue, but your own which emits key and rand) or changing the array you give to the ngFor are more common ways to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm curious, did you solve this? Did you try the ngTemplateOutput solution?

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** create a *custom local variable* within a `ngFor`. You can only use [the exported values](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) that can be aliased to local variables. Perhaps, you need another array of random numbers to use in your iteration at the same time like bellow :

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list | keyvalue; let i = index">
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio-{{random[i]}}" name="field-radio" 
    [value]="item.key">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-{{random[i]}}">
    {{ item.key }}
  </label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="list; context: { item: item }"></ng-container>
</li>

<ng-template #list let-rand="rand()">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" [id]="'radio-'+rand" name="field-radio" [value]="item.key">
    <label class="form-check-label" [for]="'radio-'+rand">
   {{ item.key }}
 </label>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: @A. Gladkiy try this and let me know if it is okay for you

Comment: The idea to use ngTemplateOutlet is good, but I don't think you got it really right. You should probably have the rand variable in the context (`rand: random()`) and set `$implicit` to `item`. Then your template becomes `<ng-template #list let-item let-rand="rand">`

Answer (score -1):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list | keyvalue; let i= index" >
  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" [id]="'radio-'+i" name="field-radio" 
    [value]="item.key">
  <label class="form-check-label" [for]="'radio-'+i">
    {{ item.key }}
  </label>
</li>
```

Try to use index, it will give you unique identifier on id and for attributes

Comment: index doesn't match my needs, I need random.